# How to store pdf file from asset folder to memory card in android

Tags: android

Hi friends
I have pdf file in asset folder now i want to store that pdf file to sdcard .and I want to display pdf in webview can anybody tell how to do?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Use AssetManager to get the pdf:

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("your_pdf.pdf");
```

and then you can write that to the card:

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File (sdcard.getAbsolutePath() + "/where/you/want/it");
dir.mkdirs();
File file = new File(dir, "your_pdf.pdf");
FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

and display it

```
Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: @benwilliams its not working its giving filenotfoundexception permisson denied.

Comment: You'll need `<uses-permission android:name=android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE/>` to write.  Try calling `String[] files = assetManager.list()` and walking through it to see if your PDF shows up.

Comment: @Ben Williams that error is fixed still not  displaying .I think problem in display code can you tell what i have to do

Comment: In what way is it not displaying?  Can you pull the written file off the SDCard directly and check it has been written correctly?  How large is your PDF?

Comment: @ben williams yes i can pull from sdcard the pdf size is very small only

Comment: In what way is it not displaying?  When startActivity runs, what happens exactly?  Also, what are you testing this with, an emulator or a device, and if so, what settings/device?